# 406 Not Acceptable: First Name field is required. Last Name field is required. in drupal services

Tags: web-services, drupal, drupal-7, postman

path : https:/www.mysite.com/infi_services/user/register 
using postman application

and  json data parameter

{

```
  "field_name_first__und__0__value":"ganesh ",

  "field_name_first_und_0_value":"ganesh ",

  "field_name_first[und][0][value]":"ganesh ",

  "field_name_last__und__0__value":" ganesh",

  "field_name_last_und_0_value":"ganesh",

  "field_name_last[und][0][value]":"ganesh",

   "mail":"mail@gmail.com",

   "pass":"pass1",

  "field_gender__und":"Male",

   "account":{

  "name":"username",

  "pass":"password",

  "mail":"test@test.com"
```

}
}

i got following  result

```
<form_errors>
    <field_name_first__und__0__value>First Name field is required.</field_name_first__und__0__value>
    <field_name_last__und__0__value>Last Name field is required.</field_name_last__und__0__value>
</form_errors>
```

when i inspect using f12  my register form i see 
input field with name  **field_name_first[und][0][value]**

how to pass this key so that this error gone?

Thanks 
Ranjeet Gholave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with android site application if your code working in core php then it going to work your application in android too

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you write any JSON validate using www.jsonlint.com it shows where exactly is the error.
For your code check the first line you need to add '{', '[' just after "first"